# How can I use innerHTML to create a clickable link based on user's input?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to prompt the user to enter a website, and then have that website show on the page as a clickable link. Can someone help me figure out why this isn't working?

HTML:

```
<h5 class="user-output">My favorite website is <span id="favorite-
website">...</span></h5>

<button class="button-primary" onclick=app.setWebsite()>Set 
Website</button>
```

When the user clicks 'Set Website' a dialog box with the prompt should pop up, but with the code below no box shows.

JS:

```
app.setWebsite = function setWebsite() {
var favWebsiteInput = prompt("What is your favorite website?")
var getWebsite = document.getElementById("favorite-website")
getWebsite.innerHTML = <a href="favWebsiteInput">
  <span class="favorite-website"></span>find out here!</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<h5 class="user-output">My favorite website is
    <span id="favorite-website">...</span>
</h5>

<button class="button-primary" onclick="app.setWebsite()">Set Website</button>
```

JS:

```
app = {};
app.setWebsite = function() {
    var favWebsiteInput = prompt("What is your favorite website?");
    var getWebsite = document.getElementById("favorite-website");

    getWebsite.innerHTML = '<a href=http://' + favWebsiteInput + '>find out here!</a>';
};
```

Comment: @ellie Any time :)

Answer (score 0):

This code would work.

```
if(!app)app = {};
app.setWebsite = function setWebsite() {
    var favWebsiteInput = prompt("What is your favorite website?")
    var getWebsite = document.getElementById("favorite-website")
    getWebsite.innerHTML = '<a href="favWebsiteInput"><span class="favorite-website"></span>find out here!</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.website = function setWebsite()
{
  var favWebsite =  document.getElementById('favourite-website');
     favWebsite.addEventListener("click", function(){
        favWebsite.innerHTML = `<a href="`+favWebsiteInput+`">
  <span class="favorite-website"></span>find out here!</a>`;
    });
}
```